# Slow down EventHubTrigger in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a simple Azure function which:

- as input uses EventHubTrigger
- internally write some events to the Azure Storage

During some part of the day the average batch size is around 250+, which is great because I write less block to Azure Storage, but for most of the time the batch size is less then 10.
Is there anyway to force EventHubTrigger to wait until there are more than 50/100/200 messages to process, so I can reduce append blocks in Azure Storage.

Answer (score 0):

**Update--**

The [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#eventhub) file contains settings that control Event Hub trigger behavior. See the [host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings) section for details regarding available settings.

You can specify a timestamp such that you receive events enqueued only after the given timestamp.

[initialOffsetOptions/enqueuedTimeUtc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#:%7E:text=initialOffsetOptions/enqueuedTimeUtc):  Specifies the enqueued time of the event in the stream from which to start processing. When `initialOffsetOptions/type` is configured as `fromEnqueuedTime`, this setting is mandatory. Supports time in any format supported by [DateTime.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime), such as `2020-10-26T20:31Z`. For clarity, you should also specify a timezone. When timezone isn't specified, Functions assumes the local timezone of the machine running the function app, which is UTC when running on Azure. For more information, see the [EventProcessorOptions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.eventprocessoroptions.initialoffsetprovider).

**---**

If I understand your ask correctly, you want to hold all the received events until a certain threshold and then process them at once in a singe Azure function run.

To receive events in a batch, make string or EventData an array. In the binding configuration properties that you set in the `function.json` file and the EventHubTrigger attribute. Set `function.json` property "**cardinality**"  to "**many**" in order to enable batching. If omitted or set to one, a single message is passed to the function. In C#, this property is automatically assigned whenever the trigger has an array for the type.

**Note:** When receiving in a batch you cannot bind to method parameters with event metadata and must receive these from each EventData object

Further, I could not find an explicit way to do this task. You would have to [modify your function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/processing-100-000-events-per-second-on-azure-functions/#:%7E:text=batches%20of%20messages.), like using a [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function#:%7E:text=Configure%20the%20new%20trigger%20with%20the%20settings%20as%20specified%20in%20the%20table%20below%20the%20image%2C%20and%20then%20select%20Create%20Function.) or use the [blob queue storage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function) to read all messages in a buffer, and then [write to a blob via blob binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob).

Comment: I have batch processing, but depends on the time/weekday/other I have in batch average 2 messages. I will prefer to wait until there is 100 instead.

Comment: am afraid there is only maxBatchSize not minimum