# How to get latest logs on Azure Function after deployment

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

I am running an Azure Function on Java with EventHub trigger. Now the function receives 1000s of messages per min. It is becoming difficult to track your changes after deployment as the logs are showing one day old content. Now even though I have commented out certain lines and added other lines to verify my changes, after deployment it still shows the commented lines. When I observed it, those were old logs. Is there any way to change that? As I have to wait a long time to see my changes on kudu console.
Where do I change the settings, so that my changes will reflect on basis of current changes?

**Update:**
I am using below setup in host.json. So may be because of the property "initialOffsetOptions/type" my function is processing already processed events after each deployment. I have got this link [Slow down EventHubTrigger in Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035804/slow-down-eventhubtrigger-in-azure-function) but I am yet to test it. Any suggestion on this is welcome.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "eventHubs": {
            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 5,
            "eventProcessorOptions": {
                "maxBatchSize": 256,
                "prefetchCount": 512
            },
            "initialOffsetOptions": {
                "type": "fromStart",
                "enqueuedTimeUtc": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now even though I have commented out certain lines and added other lines to verify my changes, after deployment it still shows the commented lines.

Make sure you check your deployment is done. And check for the Deployment history and last modified details of deployments in an **Activity Log**. (Resource Group -> Deployments -> Activity Log)

[image]

> Is there any way to change that? As I have to wait a long time to see my changes on kudu console. Where do I change the settings, so that my changes will reflect on basis of current changes?

If you are using Consumption Plan, make sure you have to wait till your Function app restarts after deployment. After Deployment the Consumption Plan will take some time to **sync the function trigger** operation.

To avoid the problems, you can use the **Premium App Service plan** or enable **Always On** feature in your app service plan.

Comment: Everything looks fine from deployment point, The function is running. My Only concern is that I am seeing old logs on Kudu Console with previous changes, not the current ones. The logs starts streaming from old days, not the present time. Plan we use is EP.

Comment: If the deployment done with the changes check your updated code in a KUDU Console. Once it is updated with the latest changes then you can be able to view the latest updated logs.

Comment: Yeah, I did exactly that. But only problem is that the console is showing older logs first and I have to wait till one hour for my changes to come up. I wanted to know how to stop seeing the older logs. Messages flooding through eventhub makes the task difficult. Is there a setup in azure function to restrict seeing old logs?

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting old logs in KUDU Console. Provide sample code to check further. Refer [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/understanding-serverless-cold-start/)

Comment: Okay, I think I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69035804/slow-down-eventhubtrigger-in-azure-function but I am yet to try. The reason my function starts processing older messages in eventhub because the host.json property "initialOffsetOptions/type" was set as "fromStart". Hence it was picking everthing in EH from the start. I have to change it to "fromEnqueuedTime" or "fromEnd" to check it.